# Rank Arrayformula does not work with COUNTIF

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, count, match, rank

I'm using this formula in Google Sheets to RANK rows based on TOT column. It works well if I put the formula in E2 and drag over the column, but I want to put this formula inside an arrayformula and it's not working. How could I arrayformulize this?

```
=RANK.EQ(I3;$I$3:$I;0)+COUNTIF($I$3:I3;I3)-1
```

*=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK.EQ(I3;$I$3:$I;0)+COUNTIF($I$3:I3;I3)-1) This doesn't work*

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0ralOL6nv5Cv_L5La4x8q5XrlX56oVFJHJqgz-aj94/edit

Note: the CountIf part is important because I don't want duplicated ranking numbers if there's a draw between two rows. Without COUNTIF the arrayformula works well but I don't want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT({SORT(ROW(D2:D); D2:D; )\ROW(D2:D)-1});;2)
```

[image]

---

### update

```
=SORT(ROW(D2:D)-1; SORT(ROW(D2:D); D2:D;;C2:C;); 1)
```

or:

```
=SORT(ROW(D2:D)-1; SORT(ROW(D2:D); D2:D;;C2:C; 1); 1)
```

Comment: this is a very cool approach! I believe you can ditch the `INDEX(;;2)` if you do something like this: `=SORT(ROW(D2:D)-1;SORT(ROW(D2:D); D2:D; );1)`

Comment: thank you @player0 . How could this formula be changed to give the higher rank (with equal TOT value) based on the C column?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. It sorts the sequence of numbers (1 to 14 in this case) according to the ascending order of D2:D; and then finds out with MATCH in which order they were left:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D2:D));SORT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D2:D));FILTER(D2:D;D2:D<>"");0);0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sheet you've shared doesn't match the formula you have.

Here's a formula that works with the sheet you've shared:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK.EQ(D2:D;D2:D;0)+COUNTIFS(D2:D;D2:D;ROW(D2:D);"<="&ROW(D2:D))-1)
```

When using ArrayFormula you have to provide ranges to the functions parameters (and you don't need absolute references since you aren't going to drag the formula).

In this case it was slightly more complex as that `COUNTIF` you have must be done with a `COUNTIFS`.